# Slate.js prevent block deletion

Tags: slate.js

Which way I can prevent user to remove specific block from slate.js editor (or inform user that block will be deleted) my goal is protect information from accidental removal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar.

One way that I found was - by preventing default `deleteForward` and `deleteBackward` invocation when inside that node.

For example I have a `front-matter` node that contains *meta-information* about the document and I'd like the user to edit it but never remove from the tree.

`text` node is editable and this is the schema

```js
{
    type: 'front-matter',
    children: [{ text: 'Welcome to the document' }],
}
```

And this is the plugin

```js
export const withFrontmatter = (editor: Editor) => {
    const { deleteForward } = editor;

    editor.deleteForward = (unit: TextUnit) => {
        const [frontmatter] = Editor.nodes(editor, {
            match: (node) =>
                !Editor.isEditor(node) && Element.isElement(node) &&
                node.type === 'front-matter'
        });

        if (
            !!frontmatter &&
            Element.isElement(frontmatter[0]) &&
            Editor.isEmpty(editor, frontmatter[0])
        ) {
            return;
        }

        deleteForward(unit);
    };

    return editor;
};
```

Identical logic for `deleteBackward` and you have an un-deletable node.

`Editor.isEmpty(editor, frontmatter[0])` checks if the inner `text` fragment is empty.

Answer (score 1):

In slate, all the delete / remove node seems to be happening the endpoint of

```js
editor.apply('remove-node', options);
```

Therefore, adding plugins  worked for me as shown below:

```js
const withPreventBlockDeletion = editor => {
  const { apply } = editor
    
  editor.apply = operation => {
    if (operation.type === 'remove_node') {
      const { node } = operation;
      if (node.type === 'your block type') {
        // Prevent certain element/node to be deleted
        return;
      }
    }
    
    // Other cases
    apply(operation)
  }
    
  return editor
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the property: `contentEditable={false}` to the element renderer, this will prevent this element (node) from being changed in the editor